# How to download old ISO

Tags: ubuntu, iso-image, kde

Since I've upgraded my installed packages, I'm experiencing a misbehaviour in some software, probably because a new version of some package is not fully compatible with the app.

I'm using KDE Neon (based on Ubuntu 22.04) as my preferred distro.

I'd like to download a version a little old, and test if the problem is gone.

I think every few days the ISO is regenerated in order to include new updates.
This behavior is normally good, but prevents me to get older versions.
I'm downloading from [here](https://neon.kde.org/download).

No archive to previous ISO's are available.

I've only found [this](https://archive.neon.kde.org/), but don't know how to use it and I don't see any ISO.

**UPDATE**:
The software is GlobalProtect, a closed source VPN app from PaloAlto, that internally uses Qt libraries.

I suppose some Qt library has been updated and the app freezes.

With a Gnome desktop it works ok.

Comment: I would be very surprised if downloading an older ISO of the same version (e.g: 22.04) would help - most of the packages will likely be downloaded from an online package repository, rather than bundled in the image... if you have a suspect package, you may be able to downgrade that or find a previous build of just that package - if that works, you could place a hold on the specific package to prevent updates.

Comment: As @Attie states, you'll have to diagnose at the *package* level, **unless you simply restore all from your last full drive image, and then forbid all updates.** You might get more help here if you were more specific about "some software", and the date on which the issue was noticed.

Comment: maybe it's in here somewhere ... https://download.kde.org/stable/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure that an ISO of an old release will help you much (as some noted in the comments.)

But here you can get (download speeds are slow, but working) a copy of older release ISOs from the Web Archives:
`https://web.archive.org/web/*/https://mirrors.ocf.berkeley.edu/kde-applicationdata/neon/images/user/*`

The latest (not current) one seems to be ***neon-user-20231026-0716.iso***:
https://web.archive.org/web/20231030112901/https://mirrors.ocf.berkeley.edu/kde-applicationdata/neon/images/user/20231026-0716/neon-user-20231026-0716.iso

Comment: Thanks, I can now test with live images.